# asymptotic behavior of a singular integral

Tags: cv.complex-variables

What is the asymptotic behavior of the integral
$$\int\int_{\mathbb C}\frac{f(z, \bar z)}{(z-a)(\bar z- \bar a_0)}|dz|^2$$
as $a\to a_0$?  The function $f$ is from $C^\infty_0({\mathbb C})$ with compact support in a vicinity of $a_0$.

For a similar integral without conjugation $$F(a, a_0)=\int\int_{\mathbb C}\frac{f(z, \bar z)}{(z-a)(z-a_0)}|dz|^2$$ the asymptotic expansion is known to be 
$$-\pi f(a_0)\frac{\bar a-\bar a_0}{a-a_0}+{\rm v.\  p.\ }\int\int_{{\mathbb C}}\frac{f(z, \bar z)}{(z-a_0)^2}|dz|^2+O(|a-a_0|)$$
(and that is not too difficult to prove).

Answer (score 2):

I am awfully sorry: it is trivial. PLEASE WITHDRAW!!

Pretty standard: reduce to 
$$\int\int\frac{g(z)}{(z-b)\bar z} dz\wedge d\bar z\,,$$
then apply Stokes formula to
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int\int_{{\mathbb C}\setminus  (\{|z|<\epsilon\}\cup\{|z-b|<\epsilon\})}d\left(\frac{\log|z-b|}{\bar z}g(z, \bar z)d\bar z\right)$$
and get the asymptotics
$$\pi i g(0)\log|b| -\int\int_{{\mathbb C}}\frac{\log |z|}{\bar z}g_z |dz|^2+o(1)$$

Comment: If you're satisfied with this result, you can accept this answer to keep the question from being bumped to the front page.